# Why does building an Android kernel need a toolchain, but compiling the entire source does not?

Tags: kernel, compiling, android, cross-compilation, toolchain

As seen [here](http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html), compiling the Android kernel requires a prebuilt GCC toolchain (or the equivalent from the Android NDK). Cross-compilation makes sense; we are compiling code *for* a device with a different platform.

However, the [guide to compiling the Android source](http://source.android.com/source/building-running.html) does not anywhere require that one download a toolchain or NDK, and my understanding is that none of the tools used (SDK, etc.) contain a toolchain, either.

But of course compiling the source from scratch also builds the kernel. What's going on -- why do we need a gcc toolchain when building the kernel one way, but not the other?

Comment: I'd *guess* that the answer is that as part of building the full thing, you're building the toolchain. Check if gcc source is part of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the gcc toolchain for both.

The toolchain is part of the android source tree. Before you build the entire android source, you use the "lunch" tool, which sets the environment variables such that a prebuilt toolchain can be used.

http://source.android.com/source/building-running.html#choose-a-target

The page about compiling the android kernel has different instructions because it assumes you want to build only a kernel and may not even download the entire android source tree. That's why it explains how to get and choose a toolchain in a manner different than through "lunch".